# Why is it not possible to update a value in a HashMap using bracket [ ] notation?

Tags: rust, hashmap, updating

I wrote a "count all character occurrences in a string" function with Rust, but updating/adding to the values does not work with bracket notation.
Why is that?

What works is this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let myString = "Go ahead and count all my characters";

    let mut myMap = HashMap::new();

    for ch in myString.chars() {
        *myMap.entry(ch).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }
}
```

What does NOT work is:

```
for ch in myString.chars() {
    myMap.entry(ch).or_insert(0);
    *myMap[&ch] += 1;
}
```

In the latter case, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0614]: type `{integer}` cannot be dereferenced
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         *myMap[&ch] += 1;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This makes sense because they are copied and stored on the stack (if I understand correctly), but you also cannot add 1 to them if you do not try do dereference the value. It looks like the first version is the only option I have; is that correct? Why does it work there?

Comment: the first version is a lot better, it will not panic if the key is not present.

Comment: @Stargateur it also never panics on second, it is effectively safe because of the previous line but more error prone ofc

Answer (score 3):

In Rust the operators can be overloaded by the [standard operator traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html).  The *index* operator (or sometimes called as *subscript* operator) has two flavours: [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html).  If you are looking at the documentation of the [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) it only implements the former, thus it cannot modify the returned referenced value.

Comment: hashmap should not even implement Index according to index rule to cost O(1), that for example why string doesn't implement index.

Comment: @Stargateur what makes you think that?  In theory accessing, inserting, and removing elements of a hash table have the average time complexity of O(1) and the worst case is O(n).  Space complexity on the other hand is O(n).

Comment: `O(1)` != `O(1)~` I don't like people always think access hashmap is `O(1)`, this simplify the problem too much and cause people to forget hashmap have a cost, and miss use it. Also, use index notation for hashmap can make it panic. Not very good too. Rust std break their own rule of index is O(1) by implementing index for hashmap.

Comment: You are comparing apples to pears.  Hash table is indeed O(1): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table